# How to set up One to Many connections without any user interactions

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, one-to-many, p2p

We found multiple ways to connect two device with a Peer-to-Peer connection using things like Bluetooth and Wifi direct. Problem is, each device need the user to accept or confirm the connection.

We would like to make a One to Many system where everyone can connect to one device. This device need to manage all the connections incoming without any user interaction (really independant) and then display in our activity some informations receive from all the connected device.

We're looking for some good examples on how we can do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you just use basic TCP Server?

**EDIT/Answer to comment:**
Yes it is possible, here is one of my [sample apps](https://github.com/WithoutCaps/TCPClientAndServerAndroidSample), tho servers can be created on ports above 1024

Comment: All the devices need to be any type of Android device using one single App (our app). Is it possible to run a TCP server in an android activity ?

Comment: I CALL IT FEATURE!!! :D looks like i forgot to start a thread :D PRO TIP: fully test your apps!!! I may fix few other mini bugs tonight (just fixed that thread thingy)